# code for scan a QRCode image and upload to server in j2me

Tags: java-me, qr-code

I created a code for upload a image to server image taken resource file.

But now I want code for scan a QRCode  image and upload to server in j2me.

Comment: I apologize for the late reply...because i didn't see ur comment,actually i tried image capture through camera..also i taken image from resource and encode the image, what my project is to scan a  image and encode the image and upload to server in j3me......i want some sample code for that ..........Thanks in advance.........Alagu senthil

Answer (score 3):

Use [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) for scanning the QRCode in Java ME. For more info, [refer this article.](http://qrdemo.com/qrmidlet/)

**Note:** [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/) is a framework for developing Java ME applications. You can easily developing the [QRCode application](http://codenameone.blogspot.in/2012/04/code-of-zebra-zxing-on-codename-one.html) by using Codename One.